# Char.IsLetterOrDigit in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I create scalar function in pure TSQL to get the same result as `Char.IsLetterOrDigit()` in C#?

I need all the unicode letters and numbers including special letters like `ç` etc.

UPDATE:
For example, the input is "-š*đčć1ž/", and the result should be only "šđčć1ž"

Comment: There's the [`UNICODE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) function to get the code point but after that you're on your own. You'd have to basically have the tables from the unicode standard to be able to perform a lookup, because there's no formulaic way to determine that they're in those categories.

Comment: `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` returns a bool, you seem to want something that returns a string. Can you clarify what you really want?

Answer (score 3):

@LasseV.Karlsen's comment made me realize I had to rework my code, I hope this will work:

```
create function [dbo].[f_clense]
(
    @txt nvarchar(8000)
) returns nvarchar(8000)
as
begin
declare @firstupperletter char(1)='A'
declare @lastupperletter char(1)='Z'
declare @firstlowerletter char(1)='a'
declare @lastlowerletter char(1)='z'
declare @firstnumber char(1)='0'
declare @lastnumber char(1)='9'
declare @len int = len(@txt)

while @len > 0
select @txt = case when @c between @firstupperletter and @lastupperletter
                     or @c between @firstlowerletter and @lastlowerletter
                     or @c between @firstnumber and @lastnumber
                   then @txt 
                   else stuff(@txt, @len, 1, '') 
              end,
       @len += -1

return @txt
end
go
select [dbo].[f_clense]('abc&d23/')
```

Comment: +1  Is there a reason you did not check for digit first?

Comment: @Blam no, I haven't considered which part of the case is faster. But it is most likely the digit part. Good point

Comment: Since the specification is that he wants what char.IsLetterOrDigit provides, then this is nowhere near that. There's lots of unicode code points that are classified as letters without having both an uppercase and lowercase code point. Additionally, unicode digits are more than just 0-9.

Comment: There's 310 code points classified as digits, and 47672 classified as letters, where 45782 of them does not have a distinct uppercase and lowercase representation, at least not in my default culture.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen pardon my ignorance. I don't know that many languages. The solution I provided works for those languages I do know(I hope). I imagine it will work for Norwegian as well. Does this mean there is no valid solution in mssql ?

Comment: There is no valid built-in solution in T-SQL, correct. You can make do with a lookup table, or wrapping the .NET function in a SQL-CLR procedure, but unfortunately something that handles everything that char.IsLetterOrDigit does does not exist in T-SQL or SQL Server directly like that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you for your imput. I rewrote my code, if you spot another significant error in it, I will erase it.

Comment: Did you test on the OP input "-š*đčć1ž/"  ?

Comment: @Blam I would it i could. Problem is i don't know which alphabet it is. But I am sure the QA can replace first and last letter in the alphabet in the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same result as Char.IsLetterOrDigit() in .NET then I would just go with CLR integration
I don't think you are going to do this in in pure TSQL
Now you could just do it once and populate a table in SQL with all unicode chars that IsLetterOrDigit

[Char.IsLetterOrDigit Method (Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cay4xx2f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)